# Replacing warning message with custom text

Tags: warning-messages

I am using the following code to determine the maximum of a function:

```
f[x_] = Log[3/10, 3 - 2 x - x^2]
xr = FunctionDomain[f[x], x]
Maximize[{f[x], xr}, x]
```

As the maximum value does not exist, a warning message is returned:

> Maximize::natt: The maximum is not attained at any point satisfying the given constraints.

I want to modify the code such that it doesn't give a warning message, but prints

> The function does not have a maximum value in this interval

when the maximum does not exist, and give the maximum otherwise.

Comment: `{Limit[f[x], x -> -3], Limit[f[x], x -> -1]}`

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/frontendobject/RemoveFromEvaluationQueue.html

Comment: @cvgmt There is a big problem with this, as the maximum or minimum value of a function may not necessarily be obtained at the endpoint of the interval

Comment: [Once again](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284086/how-to-automatically-solve-the-coordinates-of-a-fixed-point-passing-through-a-pa#comment707520_284087), please put more effort in understanding the code you've found/obtained, don't blindly use them, **at least check the document of the  functions you don't know**. `Check` already appears in following questions of yours: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/282329/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/284016/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/282327/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/282362/1871.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using `Check`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = Log[3/10, 3 - 2 x - x^2]
xr = FunctionDomain[f[x], x]
FunctionRange[f[x], x, y]
Quiet@Check[Maximize[{f[x], xr}, x], 
  "The function does not have a maximum value over this interval", 
  Maximize::natt]
```

You can also specify a list of error messages.

Comment: ```Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = Log[3/10, 3 + 2 x + x^2]
xr = FunctionDomain[f[x], x]
FunctionRange[f[x], x, y]
Quiet@Check[Maximize[{f[x], xr}, x], 
  "The function does not have a maximum value over this interval", 
  Maximize::natt]
Quiet@Check[Minimize[{f[x], xr}, x], 
  "The function does not have a minimum value over this interval", 
  Minimize::natt]
Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}]```